# Use Powershell to find DB's in compatibility range

Tags: 2013, powershell

When I am doing updates to SharePoint I have a PowerShell script to provision the DB's that need to be upgraded.  It looks like this:

```
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.name -eq "MSS_ENT_PRD_CONFIG"}).Provision() 
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.name -eq "MSS_ENT_PRD_SVC_AppMgmt"}).Provision()
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.name -eq "MSS_ENT_PRD_SVC_BDC"}).Provision()
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.name -eq "MSS_ENT_PRD_SVC_SubSttngs"}).Provision()
(Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.name -eq "MSS_ENT_PRD_SVC_Usage"}).Provision()
```

Is there a way in PowerShell I can check the status of the DB and just provision the ones that need to be upgraded rather than add a line for each DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bool property `NeedsUpgrade` that could be used to get all the databases that need to be upgraded:

```
Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.NeedsUpgrade -eq $true}
```

All the properties of SPContentDatabase are listed on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spcontentdatabase_members.aspx) msdn page.